# Copiar registro do banco

Tags: sql, sql-server

Utilizei a seguinte query para tentar efetuar uma 'cópia' de um registro

```
insert into valores select * from valores where id = 1
```

Porém, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> An explicit value for the identity column in table 'valores' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

Acredito que o mesmo ocorra porque o meu campo ID é `identity`

Como posso criar minha query para efetuar esse select e insert com os valores coletados?

**Edit:** é importante não precisar explicitar os nomes das colunas pois a idéia é ter uma solução genérica para diferentes tabelas.

Comment: no lugar de fazer um `select * from valores`, tente especificar as colunas omitindo o coluna do id `select coluna-1, coluna-2, ..., coluna-n from valores`, opicionalmente você desativar temporariamente a coluna de identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para copiar um registro gerando um novo id para ele (coluna  *identity*), a solução 2 da resposta do @TobyMosque (explicitar as colunas deixando de fora a coluna `id`) é a correta:

```
insert into pessoa (nome, endereco)
select nome, endereco from pessoa where id = 1
```

Para não precisar escrever todas as colunas, você terá que gerar o comando `insert` dinamicamente.

Você tem opção de fazer isso no aplicativo e também através de comandos SQL.

## Gerar SQL dinamicamente usando apenas SQL

No Microsoft SQL Server, você pode executar uma query contida numa string usando o comando **exec** ou a stored procedure **sp_executesql**.

Eu recomendo **sp_executesql** pois você pode passar parâmetros de modo a reaproveitar o plano de execução ao reexecutar a query com argumentos diferentes - isso fornece uma melhor performance que pode ser importante ou irrelevante dependendo do cenário.

Além disso, a *sp_executesql* valida tipos de parâmetros e trata automaticamente apóstrofos no meio da string, facilitando a vida e dificultando *SQL Injection*.

Pois bem, considere a seguinte tabela:

```
create table pessoa(
  id int identity,
  nome varchar(50),
  endereco varchar(50));

insert into pessoa values ('Eu', 'Rua das Rocas');
insert into pessoa values ('Tu', 'Rua das Cabras');
```

Para obter a lista de colunas desta tabela, exceto a *id*, você pode executar o seguinte comando:

```
select name
from sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('pessoa')
and name <> 'id'
```

Isto retorna:

```
name
------------
nome
endereco
```

Para obter os nomes destas colunas em uma string, separados por vírgula, você pode declarar uma variável e concatenar nela o valor de cada linha, assim:

```
DECLARE @colunas VARCHAR(8000) = ''
SELECT @colunas = @colunas + ', ' + name
FROM sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('pessoa')
and name <> 'id'

select @colunas
```

Este comando retorna:

```
------------
, nome, endereço
```

Ops, temos um problema: acabamos com uma vírgula a mais na lista de colunas. Para resolver isso, uma opção é usar **coalesce** em vez de pré-inicializar o valor da variável *@colunas*:

```
DECLARE @colunas VARCHAR(8000)
SELECT @colunas = COALESCE(@colunas + ', ', '') + name
FROM sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('pessoa')
and name <> 'id'
```

Assim, na primeira iteração, a variáel é *NULL* e sua concateção com vírgula resultará em *NULL*, de modo que o *coalesce* vai agir e vai resultar em espaço vazio; e a partir da segunda iteração a variável vai conter o nome da primeira coluna e o *coalesce* não agirá mais.

Se você exibir o resultado de *@colunas* depois do comando acima, você terá o seguinte resultado:

```
------------
nome, endereço
```

Estamos fazendo progresso!

Agora só precisamos gerar dinamicamente uma query aproveitando o valor da variável *@colunas* e então executar esta query.

**O comando completo fica assim:**

```
DECLARE @colunas VARCHAR(8000)

SELECT @colunas = COALESCE(@colunas + ', ', '') + name
FROM sys.columns
where object_id = OBJECT_ID('pessoa')
and name <> 'id'

exec ('insert into pessoa (' + @colunas + ') select ' + @colunas + ' from pessoa where id = 1')
```

Você pode executar todos estes comandos como uma única query a partir do seu aplicativo.

Se você exibir agora todas os registros da tabela *pessoa*, verá que o registro de *id = 1* foi duplicado com um novo *id*, *3*:

```
id  nome  endereco
----------------------
1   Eu    Rua das Rocas 
2   Tu    Rua das Cabras 
3   Eu    Rua das Rocas
```

<sub>Obs: eu usei o comando *exec* em vez da stored procedure *sp_executesql* porque não sei o que pode ser parametrizado no seu caso específico.</sub>

Veja funcionando no [sqlfidle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ccd58/15/1).

Comment: resposta excelente, mas gostaria de sugerir uma alteração, no lugar de verificar `name <> 'id'`, você poderia fazer `is_identity = 0`, desta forma apenas os campos identity seriam omitidos. +1 pelo campo recursivo `@colunas = COALESCE(@colunas + ', ', '') + name`, nunca pensei nesta possibilidade.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica, @TobyMosque! Eu não estava a par do "is_identity".

Answer (score 4):

Rafael, como você não informou a finalidade da sua query, a estrutura da tabela ou o SGBD, vou lhe dá duas alternativas bem genéricas para o SqlServer:

**1 - Desativar o `Identity` temporariamente**

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT valores ON;

insert into valores 
select * from valores 
where id = 1;

SET IDENTITY_INSERT valores OFF;
```

*possivelmente você vai precisar fazer um RESEED apos este insert.*

**2 - Omitir a coluna id no select e no insert**

```
insert into valores (coluna-1, coluna-2, ..., coluna-n)
select coluna-1, coluna-2, ..., coluna-n from valores 
where id = 1
```

Comment: Tentei a primeira opção e realmente achei que ia funcionar, porém não funcionou, retornou o mesmo erro. O problema da segunda opção é que meu select retorna muitos valores e atribuir um a um não é viável, uma pois, a mesma instrução será realizada em outras partes do sistema.

Comment: A primeira opção é utilizada para fazer uma cópia da tabela, mantendo os ids originais, o segundo caso será criado IDs novos, e sinceramente não consigo ver a necessidade de fazer row by row ou algum problema em reusar esta consulta em múltiplos pontos do sistema.

Comment: O problema que eu estou apontando é que a solução teria que ser genérica pois isso é pego via parâmetro e é efetuado em diversos pontos do sistema. Portando eu não consigo especificar a coluna.

Comment: Neste caso tente melhorar a sua pergunta, descreva o seu cenário, a minha resposta é valida para a sua pergunta, porem o seu problema é bem mais especifico, possivelmente você terá de gerar o insert de forma dinâmica.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente você está duplicando alguma chave primária da sua tabela ou alguma coluna com *constraint* `UNIQUE`.

Você pode especificar os campos individualmente que deseja copiar (conforme resposta do Toby) ou criar uma nova tabela usando `CREATE TABLE AS` (funciona no SQL Server e no MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE novaTabela
AS (SELECT * from valores)
```